# Про(-)большеви(стс/ц)кий?

Tags: орфография

Вопрос - в заголовке. Как написать про(-)большеви(стс/ц)кий?

Готовя ответ для другого вопроса (напрямую не связанного) заглянул в Лопатина и - с некоторым даже удовлетворением - обнаружил, что Владимир Владимирович "разрешил" *большеви**ц**кий*. 
История такая. Написание *большеви**стс**кий* было закреплено словарями советской эпохи вопреки общим правилам (кулак - кулацкий, бедняк - бедняцкий и проч.). Якобы потому, что образовано от некоего "большевизм", а не "большевик".

Так вот, как теперь написать про-большевицкий? Оно-то уж точно соотносится с большевиками, а не с мифологизированным "большевизмом", специально, подозреваю, придуманным только чтобы оправдать орфографию классиков марксизма-ленинизма.

И как быть в новых условиях с дефисом?

//-------------- 
Замеченная опечатка ("большевитский" - спасибо указавшему) заставила чуть развить мысль о "большевистском" написании. 
Якобы подобные написания встречались у В. И. Ленина (сам не видел) по образцу марксистский, пацифистский и проч. 
Но на самом деле такое возможно не от "пацифизм", "большевизм", "марксизм", а только от "марксист", "пацифист" и... "большевист". 
Сравните кретинизм (кретин, не кретинист) никакого "кретинистского" прилагательного не производит.
Есть, правда, снобистский, но это тоже, видимо, напрямую от "сноба", не снобизма, ибо "снобского" прилагательного нормативно не существует.
Это я к тому, что вообще не мешает разобраться и самим "большеви***стс***ким" написанием как таковым.

Comment: Я за традиционность в орфографии. И коль сложилось - большевиСТСКий, то так пусть и будет. Тем более что к этому правилу столько исключений! Например, Владивосток - владивостокСКий.

Comment: Ларf, во-первых, спасибо, я понимаю Ваше мнение, тем более что оно было высказано не только Вами (каюсь, перетащил вопрос и на другой ресурс). Но это ответ только на вторую половину вопроса, не главную. 
Во-вторых, понимаю, что Лопатин - большой оригинал и далеко не такой авторитет, как, скажем, Розенталь.  
В-третьих и главных. Но вы сейчас рассуждаете как корректор или там редактор. Попробуйте встать на позиции, скажем, проверяющего ЕГЭ. Написание большеви**ц**кий - закреплено словарем, пусть и как одно из возможных, ошибкой считать нельзя. Производные (типа - пробольшевицкий)  нет. Ошибка?

Comment: Боюсь, большинство проверяющих ЕГЭ посчитает за ошибку и большевицкий, свежейший - а оба слова в словаре у Лопатина.  Во- первых, времени перепроверять по словарю нет. Во-вторых, не думаю, что учителя настолько изучили словарь Лопатина. Я в комиссии  по проверке ЕГЭ не  участвую, в свое время из-за зрения отказалась пройти курсы, и слава Богу. Но многих проверяющих знаю. Они бы не засомневались.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По каким причинам тут можно написать "про" через дефис я не знаю. Все правила и примеры дают только слитное написание.

Теперь по по поводу "стс-ц". По Лопатину, *большеви**ц**кий*, относящийся к [большевику](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E1%EE%EB%FC%F8%E5%E2%E8%F6%EA%E8%E9), *большеви**стс**кий* - к [большевизму](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E1%EE%EB%FC%F8%E5%E2%E8%F1%F2%F1%EA%E8%E9). Отсюда получается, что *большевицкая будённовка*, но *большевистская идеология*.
Тоже самое получается и вместе с приставкой. Если прилагательное относится к пробольшевику, то через "ц", если к ориентиравано на большевизм - "стс". Правда,  сама по себе приставка про- в значении "ориентированность, приверженность кого-, чего-л. определенным политическим, религиозным, философским и т.п. взглядам, течениям, организациям" (БТС) не даёт особо развернуться первому значению, по крайней мере я адекватного однозначного примера со словом "пробольшевицкий" придумать не могу, в то время как с большевизмом приставка сочетается хорошо (*пробольшевистские настроения*).

Термин "большевизм" использовал Ленин, он же является основным идеологом данной системы взглядов. Здесь не место обсуждать её особенности, но слово прижилось, причём не только в русском языке.

Что же касается образования слова то думаю вам поможет цитата из МСЭ 1931 года

> Термин большевизм и кличка большевики появились вскоре после II съезда Российской соц.-дем. рабочей партии (1903). На этом съезде наметились два основных течения в российской социал-демократии — революционное, возглавляемое Лениным и Плехановым (вскоре после съезда впрочем примкнувшим к меньшевикам), и оппортунистическое (соглашательское), возглавленное Мартовым, Аксельродом и др. Так как последователи Ленина составляли большинство искровцев (см.) и, в момент решения важнейших вопросов, большинство съезда, то их стали после съезда называть **«большевистами»**, а затем «большевиками» (или в сокращении «беками») в противовес «меньшевикам», как назвали сторонников Мартова, Аксельрода и др.
>   — М. Вольфсон.

По утверждению моей жены, активно изучавшей этот период, слово "большевист", она встречала в работах Ю. О. Мартова и В. М. Чернова.

Comment: Получается, по Лопатину, большевицкий и большевистский - паронимы.

Comment: > большевицкий и большевистский - паронимы.  
  
Да. О том и речь. А было неясно с самого начала7

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте! Я заинтересовался вопросом и решил ответить. Но пока регистрировался, уже воспоследовал ответ, с которым я согласен. Большевистский - от "большевист", как и сообщает Вики.

Можно я дополню ответ?

Оказывается, очень давно уже существует написание "большевицкий", я долго искал подходящие примеры. Так пишут с 1917 года, как только большевики захватили власть. Нашел несколько цитат из известных русских писателей, приведу одну, булгаковскую :

"Шпиен! Большевицкий шпиен! - Це вам не Россия, добродию"

Значит, и "пробольшевицкий"  можно писать свободно. Почему нет?

Но Антон Иванович Деникин употребил классический вариант :
"пробольшевиСТский орган «Жизнь и работа в СССР»"

Здесь в чем загвоздка небольшая есть? В произношении слова, которое все выговаривают - большевиССкий. Т не произносится, но пишется. БольшевиЦкий никто не говорил при Советской власти, звучало неодобрительно как-то. Типа фамилии - ПлевиЦкий, Троцкий. Наверное, непримиримые соперники таким способом (другим написанием и произношением) хотели умалить имидж своих врагов :

"Потрясая плетью, он заорал: ― Зараза большевицкая! Я из тебя дурь выбью!" (Шолохов, Тихий Дон)

Слышится очевидная отрицательная коннотация в такой форме слова, очень хорошо слышится. (" Коннотация
предназначена для выражения эмоциональных
или оценочных оттенков высказывания и
отображает культурные традиции общества.
Коннотации представляют собой разновидность
прагматической информации, отражающей не
сами предметы и явления, а определённое
отношение к ним")

Подводя итог, можно заключить : разное написание - разный смысл слова. Просто удивительно, как суффикс меняет восприятие прилагательного "большеви(?)кий. Отражен ли такой подход в современных словарях, я не проверял. Кажется, в такие "мелочи" мэтры-словаристы не влезают, им на это времени не хватает. Но на подобных серьезных форумах можно до сути докопаться легко, было бы желание. Спасибо, надеюсь еще поучаствовать,

Comment: Дык в вики можно что угодно написать. Не авторитетно. Ни один словарь не дает "большевист" как исходное для "большевизм".

ЗЫ А Вы не стесняйтесь. Пишите свой ответ в любом случае, только - своими словами и так чтобы было ***ясно***, как ***лично Вы*** считаете надо написать слово.  
Как бы Вам это сказать помягче... Ну скажем так: предыдущий ответ рассчитан на вполне определенную аудиторию. Я не готов ни воспринимать "ответ" написанный в таком стиле, ни спорить с ним.

Comment: Вики цитирует статью 1931 года, об этом сказано в ответе ув.
 Марк Из'а.